# MATLAB integral2 returns different value for 2 mathematically equivalent expressions

Tags: matlab, integral

I am using MATLAB integral2. I have 2 mathematically equivalent expressions. But integral2 returns 2 different values. I couldn't explain why.

`pB=0.03` and `p=0.02`

Method 1.

```
f1 = @(t1,t2) (pB>=t1+t2).*p.*(max(0,t1-p).*(t1>=t2)+max(0,t2-p).*(t1<t2));
Y1 = integral2(f1,0,1,0,1,'AbsTol', 1e-14,'RelTol',1e-14);
```

It returns `Y1=0`;

Method 2.

```
f0 = @(t2,t1) t1-p;
ymin = @(t2) max(t2,p);
ymax = @(t2) min(1,pB-t2);
Y0 = 2*p.*integral2(f0,0,1,ymin,ymax,'RelTol',1e-14);
```

It returns `Y0=1.940533323582925e-04`;

I personally prefer to use Method 1, as it does not require too much mathematical derivation. But it seems that method 1 generates wrong results.

Comment: Using numerical methods means that both cases are ultimately, approximations. One could argue that 1e-04 is more or less zero, to some arbitrary tolerance.

Comment: @AnderBiguri  for this problem, we can actually derive the expression in closed-form， which is much closer to method 2. So I was wondering if there is a way to improve the precision of method 1? But 'AbsTol', 1e-14,'RelTol',1e-14 seems already pretty tight...

Comment: Some numerical stuff is simply less accurate. Such like `atan` `acos` and `asin`, they have different levels of accuracy. The closed form does not need to be the numericaly stable one, as an example matrix inversion.